# How can I unmap <esc> key in vim, it keeps reverting despite setting it in .vimrc?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

Hi I am having some issue trying to unmap this key in my .**vimrc**. I've tried a lot of suggestions and remapping but it seems to be resetting itself every time.

```
unamp <Esc> 
unmap! <Esc>
map <Esc>^[ <Esc>^[
map <Esc> <Nop>
```

Everytime I open a file in vim and type the following in command mode:

```
:map <Esc>
```

The following shows up and I want to get rid of the `n <Esc> *:bprevious<CR>` mapping completely, that is not in my .`vimrc` file but it keeps resetting.

```
n <Esc>     * :bprevious<CR>
  <Esc>^[     <Esc>^[
ov <Esc>      <Nop>
```

The out from the command suggested in the comment:

```
:verbose :map <Esc>
```

**Result:**

```
n  <Esc>     * :bprevious<CR>
       Last set from ~/.vimrc
   <Esc>^[   [Esc]^[
       Last set from ~/.vimrc
ov <Esc>     <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

I've checked my .`vimrc` and I definitely don't have it set.

Comment: use `:verbose :map <Esc>` to find out, what created that map. If this is some plugin, you can disable it.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I've added the result to the original question. I definitely don't have that set in the .vimrc, so I'm not sure whats going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> [is the the same as ESC](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key), as mentioned in `:help <Esc>`:

```
notation    meaning         equivalent  decimal value(s)    ~
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<Nul>       zero            CTRL-@    0 (stored as 10) *<Nul>*
<BS>        backspace       CTRL-H    8 *backspace*
<Tab>       tab         CTRL-I    9 *tab* *Tab*
                            *linefeed*
<NL>        linefeed        CTRL-J   10 (used for <Nul>)
<FF>        formfeed        CTRL-L   12 *formfeed*
<CR>        carriage return     CTRL-M   13 *carriage-return*
<Return>    same as <CR>                *<Return>*
<Enter>     same as <CR>                *<Enter>*
<Esc>       escape          CTRL-[   27 *escape* *<Esc>*
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to bind Control-[ and right ] to move through the buffers. Glad I learnt it the hard way cheers.

Comment: Can this not be undone??

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the 'potentially' culprit. I would love an explanation if anyone can explain it.

These two lines when I comment them out the first entry gets erased.

```
nnoremap <C-]> :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <C-[> :bprevious<CR>
```

I'm not sure why that would affect the `<Esc>` key but it seems to have 'fixed' the issue.

Comment: That's the traditional escape sequence, and more so in Vim: `:h i_CTRL-[`

Comment: @VanLaser thanks, I learnt it the hard way :)